# HTML5 video with fixed height, but scale width to 100%

Tags: css, html

What I want to do is have an HTML5 video scale 100% width of the page, but maintain a fixed height of 650px.

The following code scales to maintain aspect ratio, which is **not** what I need:

```html
<header>
    <video width="100%" autoplay="autoplay">
        <source src="video.webm" type="video/webm; codecs=vp8,vorbis">
    </video>
</header>
```

I also tried a `max-height="650px"` but this only centres the video and leaves whitespace on either side.

Comment: You can't do this, you might want to read this [link](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#video)

Comment: On the PayPal website they achieve it.[link]( https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/home) The header video doesn't seem to maintain aspect ratio. Is this because they use some fancy JavaScript?

Comment: paypal has `width: 1179px; height: auto; visibility: visible;`... so they just have it set to `1179px`... If you shrink your browser window it does not re-size

Comment: Yeah I noticed that, but when I scale up from 1179px to my maximum resolution (1600px) the video scales the width 100%, but keeps a fixed height, this is what confused me.

Answer (score 5):

What paypal does is scaling up the video according to the viewport. But they dont go mobile, and this is a problem.

So if you want to scale your video from small to big devices, you can put your video with the basic markup:

```
<video width="100%" height="auto">...
```

This is going to scale up your video. The problem is when you go to a small viewport. The video will scale down but can be too small, so you can define a min-height and use CSS transforms to scale up the video aspect:

```
video{
transform: scale(1.5);
-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

With media queries you can define breakpoints and scale the video for those screens.

Also with some javascript you can also define a point of focus for your video (if some area of the video is more important).

Check this link for more details on that:

http://viget.com/extend/fullscreen-html5-video-with-css-transforms

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by wrapping it into two containers with a set height (750px i.e.), backface-visibility: hidden; and overflow:hidden; - so the video gets larger in total but is being cropped off at the bottom (thanks to https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/knqyK & http://fasett.no/ ):

```css
.header {
 height:750px;
 overflow: hidden;
}

video {
 display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    z-index: -100;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
 pointer-events: none;
 overflow-y: hidden;
 vertical-align: top;
}

.container_video {
 -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -ms-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center center;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 -webkit-user-select: none;
 -moz-user-select: none;
 -ms-user-select: none;
 width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
        <div class="container_video">
          <video preload="auto" autoplay loop muted poster="img/videobg.png" id="bgvid" src="//demosthenes.info/assets/videos/polina.mp4" ></video>
        </div>
      </header>
```