# HTML5 video stretch with fixed height

Tags: javascript, css

Video is not displaying at full width under a fixed height.

I don't need to preserve the original aspect ratio.

Here's the code I am using:

```
<video width="100%" height="314" autoplay loop>
    <source src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/lapka-assets/web_blur.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Also, a **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LCfiddle/Lvcvpdgw/1/)**:

Any suggestions?

Comment: That solution doesn't work. jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LCfiddle/Lvcvpdgw/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are close, all you need is to make the `height: auto` or removing it altogether. Regarding your width, if you have a limit on how wide you need it to expand, you can specify this via `max-width` and `min-width`. I recommend not going less than `320px` for min widths as this is the smallest screen you will need to support.

**EDIT** After working with OP on the specifics of the question, we have determined that to maintain fixed height on **[HTML5 Video Stretch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3779771/html-5-video-stretch)**; you need the following wrapper code:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden; width: 100%; height: 314px;">
  <video height="auto" width="100%" autoplay loop>
    <source src="https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/lapka-assets/web_blur.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
</div>
```

Where `overflow: hidden`, `width: 100%` and `height: 314px` are preserved for the inner `video` element.

Comment: If I make the height "auto" the image becomes way higher than the 314px height I need.

Comment: @user5336878 You need to maintain a certain aspect ratio due to the nature of the `video` element, meaning it is not possible to do what you intend (fixed height, fluid width) please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472736/html5-video-with-fixed-height-but-scale-width-to-100

Comment: In this instance, the video will be used as an abstract background to a slightly opaque image. I don't need to have to clearly see it.

Comment: I suggest that you wrap the `video` element in a `div` of height 314px and use it to hide the video at that height. Does that make sense?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: It's easy, post a new question :-) but before you do, give it a try so that you don't get down voted for not trying. Do a little research with CSS only

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/LCfiddle/Lvcvpdgw/5/

Comment: @user5336878 I am going to help you with this solution but I am going out for lunch, stand by :-)

Comment: While it does show up right in jsfiddle, it works fine in my app: http://jsfiddle.net/LCfiddle/Lvcvpdgw/7/

Comment: @user5336878 very nicely done! That's exactly what I meant, since you need fixed height, hiding the overflow of what is inside is necessary. However you can only achieve it via a wrapping div element. I can either edit my answer to include what you have done, or you can answer your own answer, whatever you find is the most helpful

Comment: @user5336878 I am voting to re-open this question based on our discussions here in the comments, I have also added the work around into my answer, I hope this helps let me know if you need anything else

Comment: Thanks Age. You really helped out. I also have another issue to resolve, but as a 'newbie' stack overflow has limited my posts. Is there another way to post it for you to comment?

Comment: @user5336878 there is if we go into a chat room: http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/953/q-a-with-age. Otherwise all you need is 2 reputation points to free yourself from the 'newbie' limitations (10 or above makes you not a newbie), you can go earn them by asking another question.

Comment: Apparently I need a reputation of 20 to access the room. Thanks for trying.

Comment: @user5336878 you can quickly get the reputation you need (at least 20 should be doable with relative ease). My best advice: ask a new question and take your problem there, I am sure you will find help immediately. Keep in mind: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask so that you do not get down voted

Comment: Thanks Age. Apparently I need to wait five (5) days to do that. :(  Thanks for the help.